# What is the meaning of 'the bus doesn't run out here ?'

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you please provide any similar examples ?

Comment: It means that bus service does not go to that area. Bus service usually only happens in urban places, so you can't get a bus ride in rural areas.

Answer (score 7):

> The bus doesn't run **out here** ?

"Out here" means that the speaker's current location is remote from *something*. From what exactly will usually be clear from the context. Or rather that the location is "outside" of something.

In our case, we can safely presume that the location is remote from the typical areas where bus transportation exists: cities, towns, highly developed rural areas (as @cVplZ said in the comment to your question).

It is "outside" of the "urbanized civilization", or "outside" in the sense that the speaker is currently in a country where bus transportation is not developed, and people rely more on personal vehicles.

You should focus on the words "out here", not "run out".

As for examples, here's one. A young man leaves the urbanized areas of the USA (specifically, his home city of Boston) and travels to Alaska - a region "outside" of civilization - in search of gold:

> "We met your father in Boston," put in Earl. "He said if we should ever run across you to tell you to come home."
>   "I'm not going back," was the reply of the squire's son. "I came **out here** to make my fortune."
>   ([To Alaska for Gold](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/To_Alaska_for_Gold/Chapter_6))

In the same vein, you should focus on **out here**, not on **came out**.